# will the string value match the integer value in sqlitedatabase?

Tags: android, database, string, integer

I have the query as following, the `DbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SCENE_ID` is a integer type. will a string "123" match with the integer 123 in the sqlitedatabase?

```
db.query(DbEntry.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{DbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MODEL_PATH}, DbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SCENE_ID+"=?", new String[]{String.valueof(scene_id)}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: In SQL, strings must be delimited with apostrophe.  "123" without apostrophes will be interpreted as a numeric value which parses to the type of column you are querying.

Comment: so in this case, if I use String.valueof(scene_id), it will still match the integer type value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work. SQLite is very lax with respect to types. For example you can fire up an SQLite client and connect to an SQLite database and run a query on a table with an integer field using a `WHERE` clause with a string value. It will work just fine.